# Braintree iOS can't tokenize card

Tags: ios, cocoapods, braintree

I am trying to tokenize credit card with Braintree iOS.
This is my code like in the [docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/ios+php/sdk/client/credit-cards).

```
self.braintree = [Braintree braintreeWithClientToken:self.clientToken];
   BTClientCardRequest *request = [BTClientCardRequest new];
   request.number = @"4111111111111111";
    request.expirationMonth = @"12";
   request.expirationYear = @"2018";

    [self.braintree tokenizeCard:request
                 completion:^(NSString *nonce, NSError *error){

                 }];
```

Unfortunately I don't find BTClientCardRequest class in the project, although it is there in [Braintree API header directory](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios/tree/master/Braintree/API/@Public).

And my Podfile looks like this:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, "6.0"

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target "myproj" do
pod 'Braintree'
pod "Braintree/API"
end

target "myprojTests" do
pod 'Braintree'
pod "Braintree/API"
end
```

My Podfile.lock looks like this:

```
PODS:
  - Braintree (3.3.1):
    - Braintree/API
    - Braintree/Drop-In
    - Braintree/Payments
    - Braintree/PayPal
    - Braintree/UI
    - Braintree/Venmo
  - Braintree/API (3.3.1)
  - Braintree/Drop-In (3.3.1):
    - Braintree/API
    - Braintree/Payments
    - Braintree/PayPal
    - Braintree/UI
    - Braintree/Venmo
  - Braintree/Payments (3.3.1):
    - Braintree/API
    - Braintree/PayPal
    - Braintree/Venmo
  - Braintree/PayPal (3.3.1):
    - Braintree/API
    - Braintree/UI
  - Braintree/UI (3.3.1)
  - Braintree/Venmo (3.3.1):
    - Braintree/API

DEPENDENCIES:
  - Braintree
  - Braintree/API

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  Braintree: 34538ea612eb8aa2a1187fb273ac80fd496f0628

COCOAPODS: 0.34.1
```

I am really confused why I don't have this class as well as several other in my project workspace.

Comment: Can you post your Podfile.lock as well?

Comment: @mickeyreiss https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vRr0O5eF0hJO_DA6SHdzlm0YOQL9p3rZyD1RVPL8rjc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks. Posting your Podfile.lock was helpful for determining how the dependencies specified in your Podfile were resolved by CocoaPods!

Comment: I am not able to acces BraintreeUI class even thought I have all files in my podfile.lock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your `Podfile.lock`, it looks like you have pulled in an older version of Braintree iOS (`3.3.1`). In this version, `-[Braintree tokenizeCard…]` has a [slightly different signature](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios/blob/3.3.1/Braintree/Braintree.h#L97-L101) from the one that you have used, which is based on [Braintree's online documentation][2].

I would recommend upgrading to the latest version by running this command in Terminal:

```
$ cd /path/to/your/project
$ pod update Braintree
```

There is a [changelog here](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

Alternatively, if you do not want to upgrade, you can change your code to look like [this](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios/blob/3.3.1/Braintree-Specs/BraintreeSpec.m#L20-L26):

```
[braintree tokenizeCardWithNumber:@"4111111111111111"
                   expirationMonth:@"12"
                   expirationYear:@"2020"
                       completion:^(NSString *nonce, NSError *error) {
                           /* Check for errors and use the `nonce` here. */
                       }];
```

Comment: Thanks, already did that. Okay, but how should I tokenize card with CVV and postal code? Moreover, another issue would be that I don't see VTClient class...

Comment: VTClient was removed in 3.0.0.

Comment: Please upgrading to the latest version to tokenize with CVV and postal code.